# Using stacked barplots in ggplot2 results in wrong axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I created a new data set using `tidyr`:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 ##Create some fake data
 set.seed(3)
 data <- tibble(
      year = 1991:2020,
      One = 11:40,
      Two = 31:60,
      Three = 61:90,   
 )

 ##Gather the variables to create a long dataset
 new_data <- data %>%
 gather(model, value, -year)

 ##plot the data
 ggplot(new_data, aes(x = year, y = value, fill=model)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack")+
 geom_rangeframe() + 
 theme_tufte()
```

The Problem is that the y-axis is not at the correct length:

[image]

Adding a facet_grid to the code:

```
 # facet_grid(~model)
```

[image]

I also tried adding

```
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 150))
```

however it did not work.

I als tried adding a fake dataset which  contains the range from min to max of my real data:

```
 data2 <- tibble(
 year = 1991:2020,    
 bmsum = dummy = c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,90)
 )
 new_data2 <- data2 %>%
 gather(model, value, -year)
 ggplot(new_data, aes(x = year, y = value, fill=model)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack")+
 geom_rangeframe(data=new_data2) + 
 facet_grid(~model)+
 theme_pubclean()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the axis, and this is nothing to do with the stacked plot. You're using `ggthemes::geom_rangeframe()`, which, if you view the description, creates:

> Axis lines which extend to the maximum and minimum of the plotted data.

If you don't want those, don't use them. Your call to `theme_tufte()` is removing the background breaks, making it look like there's no axis.

You can put the lines back in after your `theme_tufte()` call by adding another call to `theme()` with an `axis.line` argument:

```
ggplot(new_data, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = model)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")+
    theme_tufte() + 
    theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. removing rangeframe() result in no axis. is there a easy way to use theme_tufte() with having the axis printed completely?

Comment: do you know how I can recreate the Little gap between the intersection of x and y axis like in tufte?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Do you not want the x- and y-axes to meet?

Comment: yes correct. in the tufte_theme there is a gap at the axis sources

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer. There are no axes in `tufte_theme`. What you thought were axes were just the lines drawn by `geom_rangeframe`.

Comment: oh your are Right my fault. i am sorry for my missunderstanding. thanks for your answers